# XAML Designer can not find any files in my local namespace

Tags: wpf, xaml, namespaces, viewmodel, dependency-properties

I know this question has been asked multiple times, and I've gone through them all. Hopefully I didn't just miss something in the previous answers, but I'm stumped.

My application was working fine yesterday, but today I booted it up and now none of my file references, including ViewModels or DependencyProperties which I have defined in external files, can be found. I'm coding in VB (as you'll see), I've tried changing / adding Namespaces  and nothing!

If someone has some insight into this issue I'm all ears!

**Solution Structure**

[image]

**XAML**

```
<Window
xmlns:l="clr-namespace:PrairieWestIceCreamWPF"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"    
x:Class="WeeklyOutlookView" Title="WeeklyOutlookView" Name="WeeklyOutlookView"    Height="463.5" Width="1280" l:WindowBehavior.WindowClosing="{Binding WindowClosingCommand}">


<Window.DataContext>
    <l:WeeklyOutlookViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
```

**Errors**

*The Name "WindowBehavior" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:PrairieWestIceCreamWPF*

*The Name "WeeklyOutlookViewModel" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:PrairieWestIceCreamWPF*

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the culprit!!

At my work, our desktops are hosted on a network share. I had brought two applications I was working on from home and dropped the application files temporarily on the desktop to make some quick minor changes. Turns out there is a bug in the WPF Designer where the application will not be able to resolve assembly references if the application is being run from a share. As soon as I moved it to my local D drive, everything work perfectly.

Found answer here ->
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/75c4cc8d-9a81-4bda-84f0-f619f7493b3b/vs2010-xaml-namespace-intellisense-not-working?forum=vswpfdesigner

Comment: I've had this problem for months and it has been really really annoying. This absolutely fixed it for me! What also works is mapping a the drive and accessing your projects via the mapped letter rather than the UNC share. Unbelievable - I can't believe this problem exists. Thank you greatly for posting your fix - mark it as the answer.